# inserting embedded document in mongodb using expressjs and postman

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I'm using postman (form-data) to insert a "Tournament" document using express.js and mongoose.

The end result of the document should be as follows if I used a get by id request:

```
{
    "game_id": "62c97fd41755a3ff2a530f06",
    "matches": [
        {
            "stage": "semi-final",
            "dateTime": "2011-04-11T10:20:30Z"
        },
        {
            "stage": "final",
            "dateTime": "2022-04-11T10:20:30Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is, how can I insert the embdedded document "matches" using postman form-data, and express.js?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is missing all the relevant details (your schemas, how the Tournament document is created, at which point the matches should be added and how/where, etc).

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Actually, this is irrelevant. Please refer to my answer, as I found the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer a while ago, and I'll post it here.
All I wanted was how can I send the request from postman as form-data. So here's the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do would be to first get the document I want.

```js
const tournament= await Tournament.findById(id);
```

then update the matches property with the new match. For embedded documents, the field would be an array. Id assume the new match from postman would be stored in a variable called `newMatch`

```js
tournament.matches.push(newMatch)
```

I like to use the `save` method when updating a document.

```js
await tournament.save()
```

If you want to use the update method, it would be something like this.

```js
let matches = tournament.matches
matches.push(newMatch)
await tournament.update({
matches 
})
```